# How to capture a AppMonitoringChart static link in Access Web app?

Tags: image, sharepoint, ms-access-web-app

For access web apps launched into a SharePoint site, clicking on "details" provides a page which has the following chart:
[image]

When I check the source of that "image", The link looks like this:

`https://MYCOMPANY.sharepoint.com/THISPROJECTPATH/_layouts/15/AppMonitoringChart.aspx?Launches=Days&Data=0|0|0|0|0|0|0|2|1|0|0|0|4|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|1|0|0|0|2|0`

in other words, it's passing the data to the chart in the link itself. **I want a way to capture the link to this image (without visiting the page manually/authenticating), which would allow me to track signin status for many projects**. This, however is impossible if the image itself doesn't have a fixed path... does anyone have any ideas? Or a way to harvest the data that is fed into the chart programmaticaly?